# Populate Combobox with ID and Value both VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have below code in VBA MS-Access. Below code populates compbobox with Text.

```
Private Sub PopulateEmployers()
    With Me.cmbEmployer
        .RowSourceType = "Value List"   'Set rowsource type as Value list
        .RowSource = ""                 'Clean combo contents
    End With

    Dim adoRS As ADODB.Recordset
    Set adoRS = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute("SELECT * from tblEmployers;")
    Do While Not adoRS.EOF
        Me.cmbEmployer.AddItem (adoRS!UserName)
        adoRS.MoveNext
    Loop
End Sub
```

Question: Is there any way to populate with Text and ID both? Problem is, When I check `cmbEmployer.Value` it gives text and not ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the Combo's RowSource to the SQL command directly.

```
With Me.cmbEmployer
    .ColumnCount=2
    .RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    .RowSource = "SELECT ID, UserName from tblEmployers;"
End With
```

To refresh the list:

```
Me.cmbEmployer.Requery
```

Comment: Do I need the after `end with`?

Comment: No, that's all. Set the `Bound to Column` property to get the `.Value`. 1 = ID and 2 = Username.

Comment: I saw the Combox shows two columns, Is there any way to show Text Column only?

Comment: Just set the Column Widths property to "0; 2.5cm" (or whatever width is your control). The first one though (ID) must be zero.